# AdSense is adding a meta robots tag with noindex,nofollow - would this negatively affect my SEO?

Tags: seo, google-adsense, meta-robots

When I add AdSense code to my webpage, I noticed that AdSense has a meta robots tag like below:

```
<meta content="noindex,noarchive,nofollow" name="robots">
```

My page has no other meta robots tags. Would this negatively affect SEO for my page?

Should I add a meta robots tag with `index,follow` to my page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where does it add that ? I believe you looked in the iframe that the Adsense code generates. If this is the case, then your website won't be affected. They add that because they don't want search engines to crawl their ads or index their iframe contents.

Comment: yes its inside iframe it will case issue for my page right? bcoz i didn't add any meta robots

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's in the iframe. That iframe is a different website.